# Error creating output file output file in java

Tags: java, filenotfoundexception

Hi I am getting the below error while trying to FTP the file to destination..

Code I used:

```
 final String destinationFile = destinationFolder + inputFile.getName();

 OutputStream output = null;
    try {

        output = new FileOutputStream(destinationFile);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error creating output file");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: \bsgdata1\dba1\jubair\ftpPDF\TMPAAA6CaWnR.pdf (The system cannot find the path specified)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.open(Native Method)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at java.io.FileOutputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at com.finacle.pdf.reportgenerator.util.FtpUtil.ftp(FtpUtil.java:96)
    at com.finacle.pdf.reportgenerator.PdfReportGenerator.generate(PdfReportGenerator.java:86)
    at com.finacle.pdf.reportgenerator.PdfReportGenerator.main(PdfReportGenerator.java:35)
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.finacle.pdf.reportgenerator.util.FtpUtil.ftp(FtpUtil.java:110)
    at com.finacle.pdf.reportgenerator.PdfReportGenerator.generate(PdfReportGenerator.java:86)
    at com.finacle.pdf.reportgenerator.PdfReportGenerator.main(PdfReportGenerator.java:35)
```

Comment: is `destinationFolder.exists()` true ?

Comment: Are you trying to write file via FTP? I think you need to use some java FTP library.

Comment: As the exception says: `\bsgdata1\dba1\jubair\ftpPDF\TMPAAA6CaWnR.pdf` is not a valid path.

Comment: javadoc says: *If the file exists but is a directory rather than a regular file, does not exist but cannot be created, or cannot be opened for any other reason then a FileNotFoundException is thrown.*

Answer (score 1):

It seems like the File directory is not reachable/acceesable.  Most likely it is because either the network/ftp is not available or the path is not correct.  if you can place the entire code/project I can assist you in debuging the same